# An invariant of homogeneous ideals in polynomial rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $I$ a homogeneous ideal of $S$. Let $f_1,\dots,f_l$ be a minimal generating set of $I$ and let $d$ be the maximal degree among the degrees of the $f_i$. Then $d$ is an invariant of $I$.

Eisenbud in *Commutative Algebra with a view toward Algebraic Geometry*, page 509, claims that "the reader may easily check" that $d$ is also an invariant of the graded ring $S/I$. Any hints for proving this last statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal generating set of $I$ is a homogeneous $k$-basis of $I/\mathfrak mI$, where $m=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. This shows that $d=\max\{i:(I/\mathfrak mI)_i\ne0\}$. Now use that $\hbox{Tor}_1^S(k,S/I)\simeq I/\mathfrak mI$.

Comment: Nice! But this proves that $d$ is an invariant of $I$, correct? I have managed to prove this in an alternative way, but not as elegant as yours. How about my last statement for $d$ being an invariant of $S/I$? This is were i am stuck.

Comment: Oh wait, i might be able to use what you wrote on the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow S \rightarrow S/I \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: For the last isomorphism look [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=yZsHx9mn2OMC&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=%22Tor1(R/I,R/J)%22&source=bl&ots=wZNmlGfrsb&sig=6A8jQ5cYzL9aOn7vpKLrNVOTXYk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8ISnUo7GJfP24QTGhYC4Aw&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Tor1(R%2FI%2CR%2FJ)%22&f=true). And yes, that sequence is involved.

Comment: Got it! Its not as easy, though, as Eisenbud claimed :)